# WPF GridSplitter - How to disable mouse drag and keyboard resize

Tags: c#, wpf

I've implemented a grid splitter based on a few blog sources that basically allows expand/collapse based on a double click event.

The splitter is in between two columns of a grid that represent a screen layout with a NavigationPanel on the left and a MainContentPanel on the right, with the splitter allowing the NavigationPanel to be collapsed to a minimum width where only icons are displayed.

Is there a way to disable the default behaviour of the grid splitter when it comes to allowing dragging of the splitter and keyboard adjustments?

My current workaround is as follows

- Disable keyboard adjustments by setting Focusable to False
- Prevent the user "grabbing" the splitter by placing a ToggleButton control overtop of the same as the GridSplitter, thereby having the button intercepting all mouse clicks.

I've got a version where I don't use a ToggleButton at all and just handle the double click event on the GridSplitter but the problem with that is I can't find a way to disable the mouse dragging functionality.

Comment: why did you use gridsplitter at all?

Comment: Why use a GridSplitter if you're not using its default behavior? An expander with a ToggleButton should be sufficient.

Comment: I've got an application with a grid where Column 0 is a NavigationPanel, column 1 is the splitter and Column 2 is the MainContentPanel. The idea is that you should be able to collapsed the NavPanel to a minimum size that will display only the icons (ie not hide it completely). I didn't try using an expander as I assumed that this would either expand or collapse the entire panel, which I don't want.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly don't understand why you'd want to do this, but if you really want to disable mouse AND keyboard input, just set `IsEnabled` to false. As you already discovered, if you only want to disable keyboard input, set `Focusable` to false- this is what brought me here, trying to figure that out :)

Comment: Interesting idea, unfortunately the GridSplitter control appears to ignore the IsEnabled value. Not sure why?

Answer (score 0):

One alternative I've found is to add a handler for the DragDeltaEvent and then mark it as handled.

```
public class ExtendedGridSplitter : GridSplitter
{
...
    public ExtendedGridSplitter()
    {
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(ExtendedGridSplitter), Thumb.DragDeltaEvent,
            new DragDeltaEventHandler(OnDragDelta));
    }

...
    private void OnDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {        
        e.Handled = true;           
    }
}
```

And for the keyboard events overriding the handler works similarly

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{  
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work, at least when all columns are not using `*` sizing. I'm trying to do the calculations myself due to `*` sizing bugs in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution which works for me (though not very pretty) is setting the MaxWidth and MinWidth to the same value. In my case I wanted to turn off the use of the splitter when the user selected to close the window and show a "re-appear" icon it in the sidebar.
Unfortunately the MouseWE grippers still light up but they can do nothing.